# Regex for parameters

Tags: regex, flex-lexer, lexer, jflex

Could anybody explain me how a regex should look like if I want to match from:

*section(test)* only the string *test*?

Condition is that the string *section* has to be in front of *(test)*

Thanks for any help

Comment: do you mean `section\(test\)`?

Comment: Please expand on this, is this for multiple functions, with multiple parameters?

Comment: `section\((test)\)` ?

Comment: section\(test\) and section\((test)\)

matches: section(test)
I only want to match the string inside the braces

Comment: Did you try my answer or should i complete it with something ?

Comment: I tried your answer on the website regex101 it looks like it's working.

I tried it with jflex and there it doesn't seems to work...

Comment: what function do you use ? try `section\(.*\)`  (without the capturing group)

Comment: This regex also does not work

Comment: It might not come from the regex, give some context of how you use it

Comment: I'm writing a language plugin for IntelliJ for the lexer I am using the tool JFlex (this tool auto generates a lexer).

I want to highlight the parameters from section() so the content inside ( ) should be highlighted.

Comment: @MrWhite: It would help if you pasted some code. It very much depends on the interface of your lexer with the client (IntelliJ, I suppose).

Answer (score 2):

For the regex:

```
section\((.*)\)
```

Explaination:

- `section` : for the string string that need to be there (your condition)
- `\(` : escape the `(` to match it
- `(.*)` : capture everything (the thing you want to match)
- `\)` : escape `)` and close, which is also the ending condition of the "capture everything"

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xM2xL0/1)

I assumed you want everything between the ( )

*EDIT regex101 details :*

> - section matches the characters section literally (case sensitive)
> - (  matches the character ( literally
> - **Capturing group (.*)**
>
>   - .* matches any character (except newline) *Quantifier*: * Between zero and    unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as
>       needed    [greedy]
> - ) matches the character ) literally

Comment: The tags (if not the text of the question) indicate that OP is looking for a regex which works with the (f)lex scanner generator. (F)lex does not provide captures. Its regexes can certainly use parentheses for grouping but there is no mechanism for retrieving the text matched by a parenthesized subpattern of a regex.